# how to insert a geometry in WKB format into a table in Oracle database?

Tags: database, oracle, gis

I have a table in Oracle SQL database and one of the fields of the table is of type SDO_GEOMETRY.

I want to insert a geometry, which in this case is only point, in this table. 
I know that with something like `SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, SDO_POINT(lon, lat, NULL), 4326, NULL, NULL)` I can insert my desirable data, but I don't have the lon/lat directly.

I only have the WKB format, for example `0101000020110F00003E2773E2619649408FCD44C7C4C64140`. I want to insert a geometry which is built with this WKB format. I don't want to parse this WKB and extract the lat/lon in my code and then insert it like the way I mentioned.

What is the best way to do this?

I have done these approach and none of them worked:

```
SDO_UTIL.FROM_WKBGEOMETRY('0101000020110F00003E2773E2619649408FCD44C7C4C64140')
SDO_UTIL.FROM_WKBGEOMETRY(hextoraw('0101000020110F00003E2773E2619649408FCD44C7C4C64140'))
SDO_GEOMETRY('0101000020110F00003E2773E2619649408FCD44C7C4C64140', 4326)
```

Answer (score 0):

On the table add wkb field, and then add trigger that once you update wkb you will create the geom

```
create or replace
TRIGGER GEOM_TRIGGER
after UPDATE of wkb ON your_table 
for each row
when (new.wkb IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
:new.geom := SDO_UTIL.FROM_WKBGEOMETRY(new.wkb);
END;
```